# CSS: Transition na <li>

Tags: javascript, html, css, transição

Boa tarde gente, to com um problema. Basicamente eu preciso que minha lista li apareça com um efeito de transition 2s ease quando chamo ela com o javascript (é um menu hamburguer). O background do menu aparece com a transition, mas a lista n

o codigo é esse:

```
    .nav {
        width: 600px;
        height: 100px;
        transform: translate(-46%,66%);
        display: none;
        transition: 1s ease;
    }
    .change {
        display: block;
        
    }
```

percebam que minha lista está com `display:none`, p ela nao ficar visivel.
o `.change` vem do javascript, colocando o `display block` quando eu dou o `onclick` no menu. (ai aparece a lista)
o problema é q a lista nao vem com a transition q eu coloquei ali, ela simplesmente aparece 0,0

Answer (score 2):

A propriedade **display** não utiliza da transição. Para realizar esta alteração de visibilidade pode ser feita da seguinte forma:

```js
function exibirItem() {
    document.getElementById('teste').classList.toggle('teste');
}
```

```css
li {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
.teste {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="teste">
  Teste
</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="exibirItem()">
Exibir
</button>
```

Ao utilizar a propriedade CSS de visibilidade pode mostrar ou ocultar um elemento sem afetar o layout de um documento. Adicionando isso junto a opacidade é possivel realizar a transição que você deseja.

Comment: Opa, valeu cara. Deu certinho! porém como minha li está fora da div do bg, ela continua aparecendo antes do bg. Vou tentar arrumar isso sem bugar tudo. Valeu mesmo